# Spring Boot Admin Server 2.X backwards compatible with 1.3.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

Most of our microservices still use Spring Boot 1.3.5 and are monitored with Spring Boot Admin 1.3.3. I have recently started upgrading some of these microservices to Spring Boot 2.0.0 and we are successfully monitoring them with Spring Boot 2.0.2, however I can't get Spring Boot 2.0.2 to monitor 1.3.5 Spring Boot applications. The application registers on SBA, but SBA returns a 404 error when trying to access any info tab (which I guess comes from the change on the endpoints on SBA 2.X.X).

In the SBA reference guide it is stated that it is possible to monitor 1.5.X applications (https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#monitoring-spring-boot-1.5.x). I've tried this method with no luck, so my question is, is it possible to monitor Spring Boot 1.3.5 applications with SBA 2.X.X? am I missing something?.